# Optimizations in static single assignment form

Tags: compiler-construction

Which optimization techniques can not be implemented if the intermediate representation is not in the SSA (static single assignment)? In other words, is the SSA optional or required?

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: SSA is not "required" for anything, it just makes things much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSA is not required for a particular optimization, but usually makes it easier to implement some optimizations.

There are compilers that don't use SSA (or at least don't use it for some parts of the compiler): For example GCCs low-level IR called RTL is not SSA-based, Go's backend uses SSA only since a few releases. Rust's newly introduced MIR (mid-level IR) is also not SSA-based.